# Is an interface a class?

Tags: java, interface

Is an interface a special kind of class or can you say that an interface isn't a class at all?

Comment: Short version: [What is an interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) => no

Comment: I don't understand the close votes: how is this not a real question?

Comment: Interfaces are basically outlines. They define methods which any and all subclasses need to implement. Since an interface contains no executable code, you cannot create an instance of an interface. You need to write a class to implement the methods before you can make use of it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An interface isn't a class, but you could say that both interfaces and classes are *types*.

From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.6):

> In the Java programming language, every variable and every expression has a type that can be determined at compile-time. The type may be a primitive type or a reference type. Reference types include class types and interface types.

Notice though there is a special class called [`Class<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that can represent both classes and interfaces:

> Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application.

The fact that an interface is represented by a `Class` instance where [`isInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface()) is `true` could give you the impression that an interface is just a special type of class. However this is not the case.

Comment: Something that I think really helps newbies understand the point or the *gist* of Interfaces in OOP is to design your name your Interfaces with names ending in `-able`. That way you make it obvious what its intent is.

The very moment you name an interface `Bicycle` or even worse like our Microsoft friends `IBicycle` you create cognitive dissonance. But how about making a `Bicycle` `Ridable`? Or `Shareable`? And so on and so forth. It makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 9):

No, an interface is not a class in Java.

An interface is a type and all reference types (i.e. non-primitive types) handle quite similarly in Java. Often when people say "class" they are *actually* referring to a "reference type".

What *might* be confusing you is that an interface definition is stored in a `.class` file, but that's just a technical artifact of Java. In fact all reference type definitions (classes, interfaces, annotations, enums) are stored in `.class` files in Java.

Answer (score 7):

The concept of interfaces comes from Abstract Classes, where as abstract classes contains prototypes of method (or abstract methods) and *can have few of its methods defined also*, while interfaces contains **only** the prototypes(or signature) of method or abstract methods, whose definition is to be provided by the implementing class.
so from the above statement it is clear that interfaces are like 100 percent abstract classes where -
*none of its method is defined.
mentioning it again interfaces are like 100 percent abstract classes but not the classes.*

"Interfaces are contracts for what a class can do"

A reason for introducing interface is, we can `extend` only single class but interface brought ***a new thing*** `implement` in java so we can implement thousands of interface.So we can not say that it is a class.

you can get more about this [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0120__Object-Oriented/Interface.htm)!

Comment: I love that explanation equating Interfaces to contracts. It really makes the point come across.

Answer (score 5):

Interface is just a contract which all implementing classes should follow.
An interface is something like a template which cannot make an impact until a class implements it.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't actually answer the question. As I read it, the question is *not* "What is an interface?".

Comment: @JoachimSauer sorry...my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an interface is an instance of `java.lang.Class`. If you have a `Class` you can interrogate it to see if it is an interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface()

Comment: True, but misleading. `Class` can represent all types, that doesn't mean that all types are classes!

Comment: As an answer it's as misleading as the API itself. Read into that what you will.

Answer (score 1):

An interface(is a group of related methods with empty bodies.) is just an interface. Its not a class(A class is the blueprint from which individual objects are created).

notice that you define an interface like this

```
interface Bicycle {....}
```

and a class is defined like this

```
class MyBMX implements Bicycle{...}
```

So an Interface is an Interface and NOT a class

Answer (score -4):

**yes interface is a kind of class.simply say in class methods and data present also in interface method(only abstract method) and data(only static and final) present.**

for more watch it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgBv1_Plldo&list=PLbRMhDVUMngcx5xHChJ-f7ofxZI4JzuQR&index=21&t=13:52