# What does each hierarchy in java mean?

Tags: java, hashmap, jvm, hashtable, hierarchy

Looking at [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html) there are 3 hierarchies in Java

1. Class Hierarchy
2. Interface Hierarchy
3. Enum Hierarchy

Can someone please explain what does each Hierarchy represent and what is their significance?

---

**A subquestion**-

It is documented that

> HashMap is the Hash table based implementation of the Map interface

as documented in [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html) HashTable & HashMap falls under *Class Hierarchy* and Map falls under *Interface Hierarchy*, then why isn't HashMap, Hashtable and Map represented under same Hierarchy?

Comment: What does each tree in the forest mean? Looking at the forestry guide, I see elm, larch and oak. What is the significance of each tree?

Comment: A `Map` is an `interface`. `HashMap` is a class that implements that interface. Interfaces and classes are two types of things in Java. Enums are another type of thing. An enumerated type. They are also a kind of class. There are also primitive types. They are not classes, interfaces or enums. So that's a fourth kind of thing. The abstractions are not entirely concrete. They are abstractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you could show all Java types in one hierarchy. But interfaces support multiple inheritance, therefore a tree is not sufficient to show the hierarchy. Javadoc solves this by displaying affected entries multiply times if they have multiple unrelated ancestors.

But separating interfaces and ordinary classes reduces the need for multiple entries dramatically. Now, it is needed for the “Interfaces” section at most. In the case of the `java.util` package, it’s not needed at all, but it would be needed if we merge the sections, as then, `ArrayList` and `Vector` would need to be displayed as subtypes of `AbstractList` and `RandomAccess`, fore example.

They wouldn’t need to be displayed as subtypes of `List`, however, because their supertype `AbstractList` is a subtype of `List` already. Likewise, `HashMap` does not need to be displayed as subtype of `Map`, because its supertype `AbstractMap` does implement `Map` already. On the other hand, if the type trees were merged, its entry would need to be copied to show up under each, `Serializable` and `Cloneable`, which shows how distracting such a humongous type tree would be.

The `enum` and annotation types are possibly placed into distinct sections to be consistent with the separation of `class` and `interface`, as they are declared with distinct syntax as well, i.e. `enum` and `@interface`. Or because they are not really creating a hierarchy like the other types. They always have the same supertype and no subtypes that would appear in the API documentation. On the other hand, you could say the same about `record` types, but as of JDK 17, they do not appear in a distinct section. But this may be just an oversight as `record` is a new feature.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the things you mentioned are different things.  A `class`, `interface` and `enum` interact with each other but are different.  The hierarchy being referenced are how each of these things inherit from parent objects.

In Java an `interface` defines an set of API's that can have multiple implementations.  In the case reference, `Map` is the set of methods that should be available on all implementations.   The `HashTable` and `HashMap` are have different implementations for that interface - each with their pros and cons.

Best practice is to declare your variable with the interface and while you will specify the specific implementation when you instantiate the object, the using code should care exactly what that implementation is.

Answer (score 1):

Interface hierarchy means there's a base class (an interface) of which you can implement your own classes. Those implemented have to have the same methods overridden as the base.

Class hierarchy means there's also a base class of which you can extend your own classes. Those will yield the same behaviour as the base class.

The difference between them is that you have to implement an interface's methods with the same parameters as given, but you will already have the base class' methods in your child class. It's useful for bigger projects where you have to code with complicated inheritance and so on.

To provide an example:

```java
public interface IPerson{
    void setPerson(int age, String name);
    int getAge();
    String getName();
}

public class Person implements IPerson{
    private int age;
    private String name;
    
    //you have to override every implemented method
    @Override
    public void setPerson(int age, String name){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public int getAge(){return this.age;}
    @Override
    public String getName(){return this.name;}

    //does the same as setPerson, just for demonstrational purposes
    public Person(int age, String name){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Student extends Person{
    private String school;
    //you don't need to implement the same methods as in the Person class
    public String getSchool(){return this.school;}
    public Student(int age, String name, String school){
        super(age,name); // calls Person's constructor, mandatory step
        this.school = school;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student student = new Student(15,"Billy","good school"); 
        // will possess the same attributes of both Person and Student
        System.out.println(student.getSchool()); // "good school"
        System.out.println(student.getAge()); // 15 -- you can also do this because the Student class automatically has the getAge() method because of Person

        student.setPerson(16,"Billy");
        System.out.println(student.getAge()); // 16

        Person person = new Person(30, "Anna");
        System.out.println(person.getName()); // "Anna"
        System.out.println(person.getSchool()); // DOES NOT WORK
        person.setPerson(29, "Annabelle");
        System.out.println(person.getName()); // "Annabelle"

        IPerson iperson = new IPerson(); // DOES NOT WORK 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to also answer the second question about HashMap?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Map is a "base class" which has to be implemented, HashMap and HashTable (and others) implement it - interface hierarchy. You then can extend those classes - class hierarchy.

Comment: Regarding _Interface hierarchy means there's a base class (an interface)_ and _Map is a "base class"_ - Map is an interface, not a class. You should not mix these two terms ("class" and "interface") in this way, when writing about them. See also [Is an interface a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720288/is-an-interface-a-class)